# React Native fails to run when built from Android Studio: ( Module AppRegistry is not a registered callabble module (calling runApplication) )

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I am experiencing a strange situation with my React Native project and Android Studio.

**BUILDING DEBUG**

Using the `react-native` command line tools, I can build and run my Android app without any problem. (using `react-native run-android`)

However when I try and build my debug app from Android studio, i get the following error on launch - `Module AppRegistry is not a registered callabble module (calling runApplication)`
BUT, if I do `react-native run-android` first, which installs the build and launches the javascript loader terminal, and then after that I continue triggering builds from Android Studio all is well.
So it appears that using Android Studio to build and install a fresh version of the app doesn't work anymore (i have a feeling that the fact that it doesn't launch the javascript package loader terminal is a clue).

**BUILDING 'RELEASE'**

Similar problems when I try and build the release version.
I can use `react-native run-android --variant=release` to build and install the APK to a device, with no problem.
If I try and build the release from Android Studio, however, I get a new error on compile which is -

```
`Execution failed for task ‘:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets’ 
> A problem occurred starting process ‘command ‘node’’`
```

So it appears that something is wrong with my Android Studio, seeing that I can do everything I need to via `react-native` command line, but Im not sure what it could be..? I have a feeling that both the debug and release build problems are related, and I feel like its got to do with how Android Studio is triggering the javascript/node stuff. But unsure how to fix, or make sure.